# Equivalence relations proof example?

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

> Let $A$ = {$a,b,c$}. Give an example of a relation on $A$ that is anti-symmetric, reflexive on $A$ and symmetric.

The first thing that one must do to proceed with this question is to first define what these terms mean.

**Reflexive** : R is reflexive on $A$ iff for all $x∈ A$, $xRx.$

**Symmetric** : R is symmetric iff for all $x$ and $y∈ A$ if $xRy,$ then $yRx.$

**Anti-symmetric** : iff for all $x,y∈ A,$ if $xRy$ and $yRx$ then $x=y.$

Would this be the right example for it being reflexive?
$\Rightarrow$
{$(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$}

Would symmetric be like this {$(a,b),(b,a),(c,a)$}.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: In symmetric you need to include $(a, c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reflexive right.   That is the minimal reflexive relation for the set.   You can include others, but you must have *at least* these three pairs.

A symmetric relation needs to have no exceptions.   You can't include just $(c,a)$.   If *any* pair exists in the relation, so too *must* its symmetric pair.

Other than that, you are on the right trail.

Now go on to antisymetric. ...

Comment: So symmetric would be {$(a,b),(b,a),(a,c)$}

Comment: anti-symmetric would be {$(a,b),(b,a)$} ?

Comment: @LittleJon No, symmetry requires that *ever* pair in R have a symmetric partner in R.  If $(x,y)\in R$ then too $(y,x)\in R$.  Your example does not have this property. Poor $(a,c)$ is left without a its partner $(c,a)$.

Comment: Likewise antisymmetry requires that only the *only* pairs who are in the relation with their symmetric partner are those who are their own symmetric partner (the reflexive pairs).  Your example contains both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ and is thus disqualified.